# Losing javascript click event in updatepanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using an asp.net updatepanel.  In this updatepanel, I have 3 dropdowns & a "submit" button.  Using javascript, I bind a "click" event to the submit button, in order to capture the values of the 3 dropdowns however, if I select a new value from a dropdown, I perform an autopostback to change the values of the other dropdowns.  Doing this, forces my page to lose my javascript click event.  If I remove the updatepanel, everything works fine.  Any idea how I can do this?  Here's my code (my reference to my global.js file must be at the bottom of the page):

**aspx:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanelddlist" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="Description"
                      DataValueField="id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="txt sc_dropdown">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                  <br/>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server" CssClass="txt sc_dropdown" DataTextField="Description"
                      DataValueField="id" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                 <br/>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFormat" runat="server" CssClass="txt sc_dropdown" DataTextField="Description"
                      DataValueField="id" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlFormat_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                 <br />                     
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="search" 
                      OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Style="float: right;"  />                       
            </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/Tracking/global.js") %>'></script>
```

**Here is my global.js file:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setTracking();
});

function setTracking() {
 //add a click event
    $(this).bind('click', function(e) {
    //do some stuff here
    });
 });
```

What can I do to keep my javascript click event within an updatepanel postback?

Thanks

Comment: mmmh, first solution that come up in my mind: in the Page_Load, add the setTracking() script using Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock, did you already try this solution?

Comment: You are not binding a click the the submit button, you are binding it to the window object:   $(this).bind('click', ..... $(this)[0] is the windows object.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like something is missing from your code. You say you're binding to the submit button, but $(this) is not in the context of that button.

Regardless, only the controls within the updatePanel are re-rendered after your submit. This is technically a new control on the page which is why the click event is no longer bound.

Try this, instead of binding directly, bind on the document with a selector for that button:

```
$(document).on("click", "[id$=btnSearch]", function () { ... });
```

Learn more about .on here:
http://api.jquery.com/on/